# The purpose behind setHidden

Tags: ios, view

I have a piece of code that applies an animation to a view.  What I don't get is why I need to explicicly setHidden to NO before I create and commit the animation.

The animation will only show if setHidden is set to NO.

For example:

-(void)animateView
{

```
 [theView setHidden:No];

 ..Sets up animations..

 [UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

Comment: If i don't call setHidden to NO at all, it will also not show.  I thought it defaulted to NO.

Comment: Because the view itself was hidden - hence the animation is not shown. This really seems to be a no-brainer, isnt it?

Comment: you don't use a `hidden` (which is a `boolean`) property for animation with high efficiency. you should try the `alpha` properly instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step through the code using the debugger and print out the value of hidden at different stages in the code.

To print the value of hidden, type something like this in the debugger:

```
print [theView hidden]
```

Comment: It is recommended on SO that this kind of feedback (suggestions for clarifying the question's situation) be a comment on the question, since this is not an actual answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it, it was because it was set to Hidden in the XIB(interface builder).  Also if I had not set it to hidden in the beginning, the animation would begin with my view fully shown first(not hidden), and then the animation would begin. In another words, it wouldn't look nice.